# Mac Homebrew own Package, link error: No such keg

Tags: octave, osx-mavericks, homebrew

I am currently using the Macbook pro with OS 10.9.

And I was trying to install octave to my mac when I found that I have to install gnuplot before I could use the plot in the octave. So I try to install gnuplot using the homebrew. However,the brew got stuck when trying to install the *gd*, because China's network fails to link to the site https://bitbucket.org/libgd/gd-libgd/downloads/libgd-2.1.0.tar.gz

So I use goagent to download the package via chrome and try to manually install the package and try to link it using brew by the instruction from https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/FAQ

And after make install, when I try to use:

```
brew link libgd
```

the brew prompt error message:

```
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/libgd
```

And I followed exactly the process in the FAQ diy.

```
$ tar -xvf l-ibgd-2.1.0.tar.gz
[snip]

$ cd libgd-2.1.0

$ brew diy
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/libgd/2.1.0

$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libgd/2.1.0
[snip]

$ make && make install
[snip]

$ brew link libgd
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/libgd
```

The configuration and installation are without any error. Any suggestions? Thx a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things wrong here, and I'm not sure whether they are Homebrew bugs or incomplete transcription on your part.

First, the package is called `gd`, not `libgd`, so there would be `/usr/local/Cellar/gd`, not `/usr/local/Cellar/libgd`.

Second, `brew diy` appears to suggest a cmake invocation, but gd uses autotools, so that is wrong.

Ultimately, this should work if you string it all together correctly, but actually, if you have problems with reaching a mirror over http, I would just put the tarball somewhere else and edit the formula file (`brew edit gd`) to point to that new location.  Much easier, and you can even save your modification in a local Git branch.

Comment: Thanks for the reminds. I tried another mirror and it works. And for the ambiguity of the package name, I guess both formulas `gd` and `libgd` work. And I think the problem with the `diy` is that if I use the prefix to be `gb`, the linking seems ok. I don't know why. And I have a odd thoughts about the formula, could we do something so that people update the formula according to their locations. Thus these kinds of trouble will not be appeared. Thanks again.